# Getting Rid of Black Boundaries from Tiff Image using Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, image, masking

I'm getting a tiff image from earth engine using the code below, but the image I get is rectangular and surrounded by a black box.

How can I get rid of the black boundaries on the corners and get a pure circular image?

```
    geometry_circle = ee.Geometry.Point(
        [float(lng), float(lat)]).buffer(float(radius))

    captured_image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")\
        .filterBounds(geometry_circle)\
        .filterDate(starting_date, ending_date)\
        .sort('CLOUD_COVER')\
        .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4'])\
        .first()\
        .clip(geometry_circle)


    output = captured_image.visualize(**{
        'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
        'min': 0.0,
        'max': 0.4,
        'gamma': 1.5,
        'forceRgbOutput': True,
        })

    image_url = output.getDownloadURL({
    'scale': 100, 'region': geometry_circle, 'filePerBand': False, 'format': "GEO_TIFF",
```

'''

[image]

Comment: You cannot get rid of the pixels because raster images are always rectangular and filled with pixels. But you mark the nodata areas so that image viewers can treat them as transparent. There are a few techniques for that: mark certain pixel value to mean nodata, use an alpha band for transparency, or a special mask band.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for your comments, how can I select the nodata areas and mask them, is there a tutorial I can reference for these? I'm pretty new to this.